# Como ordenar um Map pela key no Java

Tags: java, android, hashmap

Estou tentando utilizar um loop para mostrar as informações agrupadas de um `Map`.

```
for(Map.Entry<Date, List<Exam>> entry : groupedList.entrySet()) {
 setNewList(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

Mas não está ordenado, minha `key` é do tipo `Date` e meus valores são uma `List<Classe>`.

Gostaria de saber como posso ordenar meu `Map` por sua `key`?

Obs: minha **minSdkVersion** é 23.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você só quer iterar pelo *map*, pode usar um [`TreeSet`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TreeSet.html) para guardar as chaves, pois ele já as ordenará:

```
Map<Date, List<Exam>> map = ...

// cria um TreeSet, com as chaves ordenadas
SortedSet<Date> keys = new TreeSet<>(map.keySet());
for (Date date : keys) { // percorre as chaves ordenadas e obtém o respectivo valor
    setNewList(date, map.get(date));
}
```

Como a classe [`Date`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html) já implementa a interface [`Comparable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Comparable.html), as chaves já são inseridas no `TreeSet` de maneira ordenada.

---

Mas se você quiser, também pode criar **outro** map, já com as chaves ordenadas. Para isso, use um [`TreeMap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TreeMap.html):

```
Map<Date, List<Exam>> map = ... // map com as chaves não-ordenadas

TreeMap<Date, List<Exam>> mapOrdenadoPorChaves = new TreeMap<>(map);
for (Date date : mapOrdenadoPorChaves.keySet()) {
    setNewList(date, mapOrdenadoPorChaves.get(date));
}
```

---

Outra opção é usar um [`List`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html) para guardar as chaves, assim você pode inclusive percorrer na ordem inversa, por exemplo:

```
Map<Date, List<Exam>> map = ... // map com as chaves não-ordenadas

List<Date> chaves = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
// ordenar as chaves na ordem inversa
Collections.sort(chaves, Collections.reverseOrder());
for (Date date : chaves) {
    setNewList(date, map.get(date));
}
```

Comment: Deu certo, existe como eu poder ordenar inversamente? Tipo "SortedDesc" ou algo assim ?

Comment: @RicardoLucas Atualizei a resposta

Comment: @RicardoLucas uma outra maneira é instanciar a classe do **NavigableMap**.

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando Java 8 isso poderia ser resolvido da seguinte forma:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Date, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    map.put(LocalDate.now().toDate(), 1);
    map.put(LocalDate.now().plusDays(5).toDate(), 2);
    map.put(LocalDate.now().minusDays(10).toDate(), 3);
    map.put(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1).toDate(), 4);

    LinkedHashMap<Date, Integer> orderedMap = map.entrySet() //
            .stream() //
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()) //
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, //
                    Map.Entry::getValue, //
                    (key, content) -> content, //
                    LinkedHashMap::new)); //

    System.out.println(orderedMap);
}
```

A saída seria a ordenação por data:

```
{Mon Jul 01 00:00:00 BRT 2019=3, Thu Jul 11 00:00:00 BRT 2019=1, Fri Jul 12 00:00:00 BRT 2019=4, Tue Jul 16 00:00:00 BRT 2019=2}
```

Comment: Minha aplicação tem um min SDK na API 23 `.stream()` ainda não existe.

Comment: Logo mais posto um outro exemplo sem Java 8 :)

Comment: Com qual versão vc testou? Testei no Java 8 e `LocalDate` (do pacote `java.time`) não tem o método `toDate()`. Por acaso vc não confundiu com o [Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#toDate--) (que tem uma classe com o mesmo nome, e essa sim possui o método `toDate`)?

Comment: @hkotsubo, acredito que sim, chegando em casa eu atualizo para a certa :) bem observado!